# Error in Hadoop MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

When I run a mapreduce program using Hadoop, I get the following error.

```
10/01/18 10:52:48 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201001181020_0002_m_000014_0, Status : FAILED
  java.io.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 1.
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:418)
10/01/18 10:52:48 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputhttp://ubuntu.ubuntu-domain:50060/tasklog?plaintext=true&taskid=attempt_201001181020_0002_m_000014_0&filter=stdout
10/01/18 10:52:48 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputhttp://ubuntu.ubuntu-domain:50060/tasklog?plaintext=true&taskid=attempt_201001181020_0002_m_000014_0&filter=stderr
```

What is this error about?

Answer (score 14):

One reason Hadoop produces this error is when the directory containing the log files becomes too full. This is a limit of the [Ext3 Filesystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext3) which only allows a maximum of 32000 links per inode.

Check how full your logs directory is in `hadoop/userlogs`

A simple test for this problem is to just try and create a directory from the command-line for example: `$ mkdir hadoop/userlogs/testdir`

If you have too many directories in userlogs the OS should fail to create the directory and report there are too many.

Comment: A million thanks. I could not figure out, too, what was happening.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue when I run out of space on disk with log directory.

Answer (score 2):

Another cause can be, JVM Error when you try to allocate some dedicated space to JVM and it is not present on your machine.

```
sample code:
conf.set("mapred.child.java.opts", "-Xmx4096m");

Error message:
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
```

**Solution: Replace -Xmx with dedicated memory value that you can provide to JVM on your machine(e.g. "-Xmx1024m")**

Answer (score 2):

Increase your ulimit to unlimited. or alternate solution reduce the allocated memory.

Comment: Care to explain why or give some references?

Comment: For increasing the ulimit- if you have lot of memory with you and you assign limited memory to JVM and you are holding lot of data in memory so, JVM will fail.
If you don't have much memory and due to misconfiguration you ended up with by assigning lot of memory so you will get this. Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough space for object heap.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a runnable jar file in eclipse, it gives that error on hadoop system. You should extract runnable part. That solved my problem.