# Hadoop JobClient: Error Reading task output

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'm trying to process 40GB of Wikipedia English articles on my cluster. The problem is the following repeating error message:

```
13/04/27 17:11:52 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201304271659_0003_m_000046_0, Status : FAILED
Too many fetch-failures
13/04/27 17:11:52 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputhttp://ubuntu:50060/tasklog?plaintext=true&attemptid=attempt_201304271659_0003_m_000046_0&filter=stdout
```

When I run the same MapReduce program on a smaller part of the Wikipedia articles rather than the full set, it works just fine and I get all the desired results. Based on that, I figured maybe its a memory issue. I cleared all the user logs (as specified in a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091287/error-in-hadoop-mapreduce)) and tried again. No Use.
I turned down replication to 1 and added a few more nodes. Still no use.

The cluster summary are as follows:

- **Configured Capacity:** 205.76 GB
- **DFS Used:** 40.39 GB
- **Non DFS USed:** 44.66 GB
- **DFS Remaining:** 120.7 GB
- **DFS Used%:** 19.63%
- **DFS Remaining%:** 58.66%
- **Live Nodes:** 12
- **Dead Nodes:** 0
- **Decomissioned Nodes:** 0
- **Number of Under Replicated Blocks:** 0

Each node runs on **Ubuntu 12.04 LTS**

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**

JobTracker Log: http://txtup.co/gtBaY

TaskTracker Log: http://txtup.co/wEZ5l

Comment: could you show us the complete log?

Comment: @Tariq That _is_ the complete log. After the map 50%; reduce 0% INFO, the above two lines keep repeating with different Task_ids. No failure message appears, the execution doesn't terminate.

Comment: i meant the jobTracker and TaskTracker logs..

Answer (score 1):

Fetch-failures are often due to DNS problems.  Check each datanode to be sure that the hostname and ip address it is configured with match DNS resolves for that hostname.

You can do this by visiting each node in your cluster and run `hostname` and `ifconfig` and note the hostname and ip address returned.  Lets say, for instance, this returns the following:

```
namenode.foo.com 10.1.1.100
datanode1.foo.com 10.1.1.1
datanode2.foo.com 10.1.1.2
datanode3.foo.com 10.1.1.3
```

Then, revisit each node and `nslookup` all the hostnames returned from the other nodes.  Verify that the returned ip address matches the one found from `ifconfig`.  For instance, when on datanode1.foo.com, you should do the following:

```
nslookup namenode.foo.com
nslookup datanode2.foo.com
nslookup datanode3.foo.com
```

and you should get back:

10.1.1.100
    10.1.1.2
    10.1.1.3

When you ran your job on a subset of data, you probably didn't have enough splits to start a task on the datanode(s) that are misconfigured.

Comment: Could you elaborate some more on how to check the DNS resolves. It may seem trivial but this is all new to me.

Comment: I did nslookup masternode, & get server:127.0.0.1,Address:127.0.0.1#53
Non-Authorative answer:Name:masternode,Address:192.168.1.1. but my IP address is 192.168.1.12.Also the error remains same. What should I do now ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and was able to find a solution. The problem lies on how hadoop deals with smaller files. In my case, I had about 150 text files that added up to 10MB. Because of how the files are "divided" into blocks the system runs out of memory pretty quickly. So to solve this you have to "fill" the blocks and arrange your new files so that they are spread nicely into blocks. Hadoop lets you "archive" small files so that they are correctly allocated into blocks.

hadoop archive -archiveName files.har -p /user/hadoop/data /user/hadoop/archive

In this case I created an archive called files.har  from the /user/hadoop/data folder and stored it into the folder /user/hadoop/archive. After doing this, I rebalance the cluster allocation using start-balancer.sh.

Now when I run the wordcount example agains the files.har everything works perfectly.

Hope this helps.

Best,

Enrique

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem with Hadoop 1.2.1 on an 8-node cluster. The problem was in the /etc/hosts file. I removed all entries containing "127.0.0.1 localhost". Instead of "127.0.0.1 localhost" you should map your IP Address to your hostname (e.g. "10.15.3.35 myhost"). Note, that you should that for all nodes in the cluster. So, in a two-node cluster,the master's /etc/hosts should contain "10.15.3.36 masters_hostname" and the slave's /etc/hosts should contain "10.15.3.37 slave1_hostname". After these changes, it would be good to restart the cluster.
Also have a look here for some basic Hadoop troubleshooting :[Hadoop Troubleshooting](https://github.com/wbsg/ldif/wiki/Hadoop-troubleshooting)